# Regular expression combining match with negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I am looking for a single regular expression that achieves the following:

- only match words containing [a-z0-9-_] (so `/^[a-z0-9-_]+$/i`)
- don't match the word "test" (so `/^(?!test).*$/i`)

Both requirements are easy to implement on their own. But How would a regular expression look like that combines both requirements in a single expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just inline your matching logic into the second regex, i.e. use:

```regex
^(?!test$)[a-z0-9_-]+$
```

### Demo

Note carefully the negative lookahead `(?!test$)`.  When placed at the very start of the pattern, this asserts that the match is not the *exact* word `test`.  However, `1test` and `testing` should be allowed, as they are not exactly `test`.

Also note that the character class I have used is slightly different than your version.  We should place `-` at the very end of the class, because `9-_` will actually be interpreted as all characters in between `9` and underscore, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Somehow I didn't see the easy solution of just inlining it.

Comment: Sidenote: OP seems to use the case insensitive flag. It's not anything major but you could simplify the class to `[\w-]`